# jQuery parents() selector failing

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I have an anchor, and I have attached an onClick callback to it, so once it is clicked, an AJAX request is fired which calls a view that deletes the image from the database. It should also remove `<div class="image-preview">` altogether, too, however that is not happening for some reason.

When I tested div removal code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgqhyr5n/), it works. The image is successfully getting removed from the database and delete_view is involved in the process. I have also tried to `console.log` from inside the success callback and I can see a debug message. `console.log($(this).parents('.image-preview'));` returns `Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object(1) }`, thus I think the selector is failing.

What could be the reason?

HTML:

```
<div id="information">
  <div class="image-previews">
    <div class="image-preview">
      <img src="/media/tmp/None/IMG_20190507_144128.jpg" width="80" height="54">
      <p><a id="115" class="delete-temp-image-link">delete</a></p>
      <label><input type="radio" name="main" value="IMG_20190507_144128.jpg">main</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div0">
    <div>Name: IMG_20190507_144128.jpg</div>
    <div>Size: 3.03MB</div>
    <div>Type: image/jpeg</div>
    <div class="progressNumber">100%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $deleteClicked = function(event) {
  var url = Urls.deleteTempImage(event.target.id);

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
      'id': event.target.id
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('spam');
      $(this).parents('.image-preview').remove();
    }
  });      
}        

$(document).on('click', '.delete-temp-image-link', $deleteClicked);
```

view:

```
def delete_view(request, id):
    img = get_object_or_404(TemporaryImage, id=id)
    img.delete()
    return HttpResponse('successfull')
```

Comment: Maybe $(this) are used in wrong context? Try to store it before $.ajax

Comment: @AndreasSchmidt you are right. You can post an answer if you like, I'd be glad to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` isn't available to your named click callback function. One way to make your code more explicit would be to store `$(this)`, as others have said - or, simply use the `id` that you're already passing anyway. For example:

```
var $deleteClicked = function(event) {
  var url = Urls.deleteTempImage(event.target.id);

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
      'id': event.target.id
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('spam');
      $("#"+event.target.id).closest('.image-preview').remove();
    }
  });      
}        

$(document).on('click', '.delete-temp-image-link', $deleteClicked);
```

Also, note that I used jQuery `.closest()` instead of `.parents()`. From the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), `.closest()` does the following:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

Check out the docs page for a description of the differences between `.closest()` and `.parents()`. The main difference is that `.closest()` only traverses up the DOM tree until it finds a match, rather than traversing all the way up to the root element. I doubt there are huge performance implications, but since you're selecting only one `<div>`, it's slightly more precise code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store **$(this)** before run **$.ajax** because you are using it in a wrong context.

```
var $deleteClicked = function(event) {
var url = Urls.deleteTempImage(event.target.id);
var storedThis = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            'id': event.target.id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('spam');
            storedThis.parents('.image-preview').remove();
        }
    });      
}        

$(document).on('click', '.delete-temp-image-link', $deleteClicked);
```

This should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for jQuery.

```
var $deleteClicked = function(event) {
  var url = Urls.deleteTempImage($(this).attr('id'));

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
      'id': $(this).attr('id')
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('spam');
      $(this).parents('.image-preview').remove();
    }
  });      
}        

$('.delete-temp-image-link').on('click', $deleteClicked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occur to me as well.
Actually '$(this)' is tricky as it may seem.

'$(this)' cannot be used in success function as it lost it scope in success function.
Try to define '$(this)' outside the success(ie, before ajax),eg

> const element = $(this)

And then in your success function:

> element.parents('.image-preview').remove();

This should definitely solve your problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I suggested in my answer.